# A Greek cipher about 2 lovers

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, language

One man and one woman once loved each other very much. But there was always something or someone who came between them and they had to eliminate that person or thing. One was so beautiful, the world would shatter upon her smile. One was a conqueror which man feared upon dawn.

This is a story about 2 lovers who were once united.

> ξ17β10Εδ17Φ20ϒ10Λ7Θ21Δ12νΓ15ΟΧ10Δ21Η13τ20ο17ϑΨ5ΡΩσ8εω18

Can you find out who I am talking about (also explain your answer)?

**HINT 1**:

> In the text, there is a clue about what you need to do.

**HINT 2**:

> To tell you the truth, the puzzle couldn't be invented before the 20th century.

**HINT 3**:

> Symbols

**HINT 4**:

> δεκαδικός

**HINT 5**:

> There isn't an equal amount of numbers as letters. This is done on purpose.

**Note**:

> The math you need to do can be done by a 10 year old. It's not that hard.
>  Like plus & minus etc, nothing complex. If you catch my drift :)

Comment: I'm unsure about tags, I added language because it has greek letters in it. If it's not ok, feel free to edit it out.

Comment: When you translate it, it becomes "
x17v10Ed17F20Y10L7Th21D12nG15OCh10D21I13t20o17thPs5ROs8eo18".

Comment: The thing got between the two lovers, is it the Greek letters?

Comment: No the 2 lovers are made from the greek letters.

Comment: So the Greekness is a red herring, and the letters aren't letters, and we're supposed to do "easy" "math" with... something.

Comment: sorry but "the puzzle couldn't be invented before the 20th century." and "math you need to do can be done by a 10 year old" do not work well together.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat I can't answer that, that would spoil the answer maybe

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat I'm just saying the math is just like plus or minus. Nothing complex.

Comment: So the letters aren't letters, language doesn't enter into this at all, and all your hints say the same things over and over again. You might want to write an *actual* hint.

Comment: @question_asker You don't need to know greek to solve it, no. I deleted a hint then. They are letters but I'm just saying, as before, just look at them as something else.

Comment: in any way, is anagram involved?

Comment: @smriti Perhaps, yes :)

Comment: Another hint, pretty please?

Comment: Still around, @Decypher?  Any other hints?  Feel like I've tried a few more things but nothing is quite coming together.

Comment: @Decypher another hint please....

Answer (score 4):

In case it's helpful to others, here are the

> <s>ASCII values</s> HTML entity codes for the Greek letters involved.
>  They're the decimal ones, since one of the hints alludes to decimal.
>  
>  `ξ 958
>  17
>  β 946
>  10
>  Ε 917
>  δ 948
>  17
>  Φ 934
>  20
>  ϒ 978
>  10
>  Λ 923
>  7
>  Θ 920
>  21
>  Δ 916
>  12
>  ν 957
>  Γ 915
>  15
>  Ο 927
>  Χ 935
>  10
>  Δ 916
>  21
>  Η 919
>  13
>  τ 964
>  20
>  ο 959
>  17
>  ϑ 977
>  Ψ 936
>  5
>  Ρ 929
>  Ω 937
>  σ 963
>  8
>  ε 949
>  ω 969
>  18`

There are 24 of the greek letters and 17 of the intervening numbers. Based on the text of the puzzle ("...something or someone who came between them and they had to eliminate that person or thing...") and hints, it seems like some basic math manipulation of these numbers may lead to the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ASCII only includes English letters. You must have used some other encoding to get these numbers...

Comment: @ffao Oh crap, good point. (Honestly I know little about these things, just Googling really.) The site I used is [this one](http://www.ssi-developer.net/reference/ascii-0.shtml) but it doesn't really seem to be backed up elsewhere.

Comment: I think they're actually the HTML entities, not the ASCII codes.  I'll edit.

Comment: @DanRussell You got step 1 done :)
Good luck on step 2. You're getting there. You have to do something with the text indeed. :)

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer Thoughts:

> Is it Venus and Mars?  Or in Greek Aphrodite and Ares?  "came between them" might mean that they were "divided". I can't reconcile the math and encodings yet.  Maybe some smart puzzler will be able to make that connection soon!

Because:

> Earth comes between them.  Venus de Milo is a "shattered" beauty.  Mars is the god of war (the conqueror) and the planet can be seen at dawn.

The rest is all Greek to me.

Comment: I like the pun :-)

Comment: This is not the answer I'm looking for, there is also some math to do :)

Comment: Not enough rep to comment on the puzzle directly. :(  Anagram, ascii (the 20th century reference?), decimal, simple math, lovers who are the Greek letters that are not Greek letters but symbols...  Definitely an enigma.

Answer (score -1):

> Sun and Moon.

Because

> Earth came between them during eclipse; sun was worshiped and feared in ancient times. And moon was part of earth, which was once part of sun, so they were united once.

Comment: You should consider using [spoilers](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: This is not the answer I'm looking for, there is also some math to do :)